# dask.dataframe.tail() returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm trying to get the value of 'n' in the last row of a dask dataframe.

If I understand correctly, positional indexing isn't an option. I don't know the index of the last row. I thought tail() would be the solution, but it returns and empty dataframe.

```
print( df.compute() ) # df has 47 rows
```

returns

```
       file            str          n 
11027  /Users/...      XXX...       901  
11028  /Users/...      XXX...       902  
...                                   
11099  /Users/...      XXX...       946
11100  /Users/...      XXX...       947
```

then i do

```
tail = df.tail( n=10, compute=True )
print(tail)
```

which takes A MINUTE AND FIFTEEN SECONDS which is unacceptably slow since I need to do several thousand of these
and returns

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [file, str, n]
Index: []
```

What am I missing here?

Note, I found a solution for head() returning empty but the solution doesn't apply to tail(). [dask dataframe head() returns empty df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524050/dask-dataframe-head-returns-empty-df)

Comment: Kindly share complete code,so it would be better to look into this.

Comment: Having this issue with tail(). Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

print with `print (df.tail(10))`

Comment: I just tried this and `print( df.tail( 1 ) )` prints out the same empty df

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://tutorial.dask.org/04_dataframe.html and find the
chapter titled *What just happened?*.
It contains a decription what can go wrong and why.

It contains also a recipe that reading a DataFrame using *read_csv*
you should pass also *dtype* parameter, specifying column types.

Try this approach.